# What is the recommended way to add emoji's to commitizen config

Tags: git, git-commit, pre-commit-hook, conventional-commits, conventional-changelog

I am using [Commitizen](https://github.com/commitizen/cz-cli), [cz-conventional-changelog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cz-conventional-changelog) and Husky to get conventional commits and get the prompts in terminal when doing a commit.

In `package.json` have this config:

```
"config": {
    "commitizen": {
      "path": "./node_modules/cz-conventional-emoji"
    }
  },
```

In `commitlint.config.cjs`:
module.exports = { extends: ['@commitlint/config-conventional'] };

In `.husky` folder:

`commit-msg` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"
```

`prepare-commit-msg` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

exec < /dev/tty && npx git-cz --hook || true

npx commitlint --edit $1
```

What is the recommended way to add emojis to commitizen config?

Comment: https://github.com/ngryman/cz-emoji?

Comment: @GaëlJ thanks yes, so I can use this package instead of `cz-conventional-changelog`? And how do I have to configure (or adjust above config) to get `cz-emoji` working with `husky`?